# How to incrementally read the lines

Tags: linux, bash, shell

i want to write a script that reads lines from file where the line starts with wt^ and p^.
i am able to get the wt^ but i am not able to get p^...
and there are 20 wt^ with corresponding p^ now i have to get 10 each wt^ with its corresponding p^ in two different files,

how can i do this?

```
cat $( ls unit-*-slides.txt | sort -n ) | grep "st^" | split -l 200
```

i have used above code

```
wt^blah blah
    p^blah blah blah blah
    p^blah blah blah blah
    p^blah blah blah blah
    p^blah blah blah blah
    p^blah blah blah blah blah blah
    p^blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
    p^blah blah blah blah blah blah
    p^blah blah blah blah blah blah
    p^blah blah blah blah blah blah
```

Comment: Which tool are you using and how are you using it? Can you share some code?

Answer (score 1):

it seems you have some spaces before `p^`. I copy pested your example and this grep worked fine
`grep -E "[ ]*(wt\^|p\^)" <file>` it takes into account that there might be n number of whitespace before the beginning of the line. You can append `xargs` with it

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex `^(wt\^)|(p\^)` to match lines that being with `wt^` or `p^`

Also from your post, it seems lines having `p^` have a `space` or `tab` in the beginning, that may be a reason why your regex is not matching `^p\^`