# how to print occurences in file?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am using this code to read line from file that starts with wt^ and p^ the file contains 900 wt^ and p^ lines, it is printing 200 lines in each file. but what i want is to read 200 wt^ and their corresponding p^.

basically i want to print 200 wt^ with its corresponding p^ in one file
how to do this?

the file is like this

```
wt^fsafasfafasffaferer
  p^pap rar otaotetae
  p^pap rar otaotetae
  p^pap rar otaotetae
  p^pap rar otaotetae
  p^pap rar otaotetae
  p^pap rar otaotetae
```

Code:

```
while IFS= read file
do 
    if [ -f "$file" ]; then
    count=$(cat $( ls unit-*-slides.txt | sort -n ) | grep -E "[ ]*(wt\^|p\^)" | split -l 200)
    fi
done < "$dest/$cfile"
```

Comment: I can't figure out what you want to do or what your script is doing. It reads lines from the file, but doesn't do anything with them -- it's printing stuff from `unit-*-slides.txt`, not the file you're reading from.

Comment: Errr http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16399026/how-to-incrementally-read-the-lines ?

Answer (score 0):

```sh
$ awk NF=NF FPAT='.*\\^'
wt^
  p^
  p^
  p^
  p^
  p^
  p^
```